# signalR: Connection ID returns undefined from angular 5 client

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to get my connection ID value after starting my connection to the signlar server (using start()), in the .done scope. But unfortunately I keep getting undefined for it. 
Hopefully you guys can help figure out what is the problem.
Thanks!

```
  public startConnection(): void
  {
      this.connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:62752');
      this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy('ChatHub');
      this.proxy.on('messageReceived', (a,b,c,d,e,f) => 
          this.onMessageReceived(a,b,c,d,e,f));

      this.connection.start().done((data: any) => {
          console.log('Connected to Chat Hub');
          this.connectionID = $.connection.hub.id;
          console.log($.connection.hub.id);//undefined
          this.registerConnection();         
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending more time on solving the problem, I was able to fix it!
I've discovered that the ID is available under data["id"].

- "data" is the name I've gave to the parameter of the done function.

I hope it will help more people in the future, since I really
   couldn't find an answer on google.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't see "data" in your original question so not understanding how that relates.